# How do I safely change the value of the primary key field in a Django model?

Tags: database, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a Django model with a custom specified primary key:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    my_primary_key = models.CharField(primary_key=True, ...)
    ...
```

I also have other models which have ForeignKey references to this model:

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    ref_to_A = models.ForeignKey('ModelA', ...)
    ...

class ModelC(models.Model):
    ref_to_A = models.ForeignKey('ModelA', ...)
    ...

...
```

I have some instances of ModelA, and need to change the value for my_primary_key for these instances.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Assuming you want to now refer new record by changing primary key (and may be other attributes). So rather than changing primary key, why don't you change other attributes? Or you duplicate a record and update instances for foreign key of new record.

Comment: This is why we use surrogate keys rather than natural keys.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if you're still looking for this, but perhaps this snippet will help: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2915/.

This is not a very good database design though, because of exactly this sort of problem.  It is generally better to use django's implicit primary keys and and create `my_primary_key` as a unique field instead.